# Remove the capital letter on every word (except the first) from the titles?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Although I liked the new designed I have a suggestion, can we remove the lead capital on each word? Like just to preserve the original input.

For instance:

> Remove The Capital Letter On Every Word (Except The First) From The
>   Titles?

would be

> Remove the capital letter on every word (except the first) from the
>   titles?

I think is cleaner and it allows  us the usage of caps when is really needed like in names organizations etc.

Comment: I agree - why does it capitalize them now?  iPod/eBay will become IPod/EBay which just makes us look silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed :) capitalization has, in general, been removed from the design; save a few places.

Comment: Thank you, Sean. But I'm still seeing it. Sometimes it seems to be on the question list.

Comment: I'll support @Sam's comment. I'm also seeing it.

Comment: Not fixed here...

Comment: Does this mean that you also intend to make the tags lowercase instead of the all uppercase they're right now?

Comment: On the question list it is "This Is A Question" but on the question page itself it is "This is a question"

Comment: Oh, it *is* fixed on the mobile version of the site.